# How do I update grub to grub2 if legacy grub is installed in boot partition sector, not MBR?

Tags: grub2

I'm trying to move to grub2 and while chainloading from legacy grub works fine, I'm not sure how to move completely. Old grub was installed in boot sector of swap partition, /dev/sda3, and was working fine there. I want new grub to be installed there as well but during `upgrade-from-grub-legacy` it suggest to install at MBR or at ubuntu root partition, /dev/sda4. How do I force it to install at /dev/sda3? Can I just do `grub-install '(hd0,3)'` instead of `upgrade-from-grub-legacy`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have verified that the new grub2 setup works, you can use `grub-install` safely.

The only significant thing `upgrade-from-grub-legacy` does is this:

```
rm -f /boot/grub/{{xfs,reiserfs,e2fs,fat,jfs,minix}_stage1_5,stage{1,2}}
```

which essentially removes the grub-legacy files from /boot/grub, you can also remove `/boot/grub/menu.lst` if it doesn't contain anything important to you.

Comment: I'm not sure if this applies to you, but i've been getting an debconf prompt asking me where to install the bootloader. This works well for me, because I have a mirrored setup and need to install grub to 2 separate drives.

Comment: It does ask about location but it gives very limited choices. As far as I understand it is either MBR or partition with Linux installed. That's not my case :)